# How can i resolve problem with bounds for export?

Tags: tilemill, mapbox

How could I set up bounds in TileMill if i don't want to upload the country around? I simply want to upload my created island in `TileMill` to `Mapbox`. 
Is there a way to do it? I am using OSM Bright for the design of my map.

Comment: Be more precise about the layer format of your island (raster, vector: shapefile, geojson?)

Comment: All layers are in shapefile format. + label layer in .csv for road names etc. I just need to upload island nothing more around the island.

Answer (score 1):

From what you say I assume that countries boundaries and Islands are on the same shapefile.
Then the best way will be to split your shape file layer in Qgis to separate Island from Land.